# How to retry Spanner commits that were aborted?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

In the Spanner documentation for `Commit()`, it says:

> Commit might return an ABORTED error. This can occur at any time; commonly, the cause is conflicts with concurrent transactions. However, it can also happen for a variety of other reasons. If Commit returns ABORTED, the caller should re-attempt the transaction from the beginning, re-using the same session.

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rpc/google.spanner.v1#google.spanner.v1.Spanner.Commit

Two Questions:

1. If the transaction is aborted, do I have to rerun all the statements that were executed from the beginning of the transaction to retry? Or is simply retrying the `commit()` again sufficient?
2. How do I reproduce an aborted commit on Spanner to verify my retry logic is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using the official Cloud Spanner client libraries. They have various transaction runner abstractions that will react to errors appropriately, including retry logic.

- If a transaction is aborted, the entire transaction should be retried.
- Cloud Spanner provides no direct way to force a transaction abort. You can set up two transactions to do something like:

  1. BeginTransaction T1
  2. BeginTransaction T2
  3. T1 read row1
  4. T2 read row1
  5. T1 commit (writing row 1) will succeed
  6. T2 commit (writing row 1) will abort

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. How familiar are you with the Cloud Spanner client libraries?

We're designing a Reactive database driver with Spanner which kind of forced our hand to use the GRPC APIs. Now we're wondering whether we should be recording all statements run in a transaction and then replay them if the commit aborts? However, from what I studied in the client libraries, it is not done this way. So now we are wondering if this "replay" strategy is feasible/valid. Curious on your thoughts.

Comment: The client libraries do retry aborts. For example, in java:

"Executes a read-write transaction, with retries as necessary. The work to perform in each transaction attempt is defined by callable , which may return an object as the result of the work. callable will be retried if a transaction attempt aborts; implementations must be prepared to be called more than once. "

https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/com/google/cloud/spanner/TransactionRunner.html

Comment: I see, that is very helpful. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

An aborted transaction includes commit conflicts. This means data you read during the transaction might no longer be valid, so all the decisions your code made - and the data it tried to write, might be based on invalid data... so you must re-do everything from when the transaction began.

To make this concrete, consider code that reads a counter, doubles it, and then writes that counter back.  Imagine your code read 4 attempted to write 8 but got a ABORT.  Upon restarting the transaction, that value might now be 5, so it would be wrong to attempt to write that 8 again. Instead your code has to start from scratch in order to calculate that it needs to write 10. This gets tricky if your code has side-effects.